# How do I make sure view controller gets notified about rotations as usual when it is presenting another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-rotation, ecslidingviewcontroller

I was looking for an answer to this for quite a while, but found nothing relevant.

In my app I have a rather complicated view controller hierarchy, with ECSlidingViewController instance at its root. On iPad there are big differences between landscape and portrait mode (for example, controller that is normally root view controller of my main navigation controller while in portrait, in landscape it becomes a container for a new navigation controller that holds all the other controllers), so making sure that view controllers get properly notified about rotations is crucial for the app to work.

My problem is with modally presented view controller, because when user rotates device while there is such a controller visible, my ECSlidingViewController (nor its top view controller) doesn't get didRotateFrom(..) and willRotateTo(..) methods called.

So how do I get my other view controllers to get notified of the rotation as well? (not talking about directly calling didRotateFrom(..) and willRotateTo(..) on them, since it won't change their frames).

Comment: I think you can observe `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification ` and implement rotation-related methods on your own (in your parent view controller of course, not directly calling from modal view controller).

Comment: However, AFAIK, it will not adjust the frame of my ViewController's view. :(

Comment: You are right. But i don't think there is a way doing it automatically. Please let us know if you find one.

Answer (score 1):

Your view controllers are not always notified when a rotation occurs, for exemple in your case.

But, one thing is always called :

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

You can check here if your orientation has changed, and change your interface according to it.

This is what I did in my App.